# bouncy castle pgp - premature end of stream in PartialInputStream

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am using bouncy castle pgp and bouncy-gpg (https://github.com/neuhalje/bouncy-gpg), I am trying to do very simple thing:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream cryptoBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {

        final OutputStream outputStream = BouncyGPG
                .encryptToStream()
                .withConfig(keyringConfig)
                .withStrongAlgorithms()
                .toRecipient(recipient)
                .andDoNotSign()
                .binaryOutput()
                .andWriteTo(cryptoBytes);

        Streams.pipeAll(input, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream plainBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        final InputStream plaintextStream = BouncyGPG
                .decryptAndVerifyStream()
                .withConfig(keyringConfig)
                .andIgnoreSignatures()
                .fromEncryptedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(cryptoBytes.toByteArray()));
        Streams.pipeAll(plaintextStream, plainBytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I am getting an exception on attempt to decrypt:

```
java.io.EOFException: premature end of stream in PartialInputStream
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream$PartialInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.SymmetricEncIntegrityPacket.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I am not using any string conversions so I can't understand why there are problems with byte array length

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, close() does nothing for ByteArrayStreams. Actually, even flush is odd here

Comment: I've asked Rahul in a previous deleted comment to close the *encrypting* PGP stream after writing. I'm not sure that this has been tried but the examples for the BouncyGPG (an library build on top of Bouncy) do *not* show that the stream needs to be closed. I'll not dive deeper until I at least know for sure that this has tried though - it's easy enough to test it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you must close the `OutputStream`. The reason is that GPG writes the signature at the end of the stream. This is triggered by closing the stream.

```
try {

    final OutputStream outputStream = BouncyGPG
            .encryptToStream()
            .withConfig(keyringConfig)
            .withStrongAlgorithms()
            .toRecipient(recipient)
            .andDoNotSign()
            .binaryOutput()
            .andWriteTo(cryptoBytes);

    Streams.pipeAll(input, outputStream);
    outputStream.close(); // <<<----
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The [example](https://github.com/neuhalje/bouncy-gpg/blob/e53d1d2/src/test/java/name/neuhalfen/projects/crypto/bouncycastle/openpgp/roundtrip/EncryptionDecryptionRoundtripIntegrationTest.java#L457-L491) in the README used 'try-with-resources' which automatically closed the stream. I clarified the README in the project to make this more clear.